# Recently added songs do not finish playing on my iPhone 6 Plus

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, itunes-match

I just recently added several songs to my iPhone 6 Plus. Here is what I did:

1. Add songs to my playlist in iTunes in my MacBook Air.
2. Sync music to my iPhone 6 Plus

Problem:

When my phone is playing the recently added song, it does not finish. If the new song is 3 mins long, when it is somewhere on the middle, it will play the next track, but the display on my phone is still the same (the recently added song).

Answer (score 1):

I had that kind of problem too. When I asked about that from Apple Support their first solution was delete newly added songs and resync them to iPhone. If they are perfectly playing on iTunes, then obviously there was a syncing problem when adding songs to iPhone. Try what I suggested. Good luck.